# How to count features from multiple different layers in a grid in ArcGIS Pro 3.1?

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join, grids-graticules, count

The multiple features (points and polygons) are all a toxic chemical from different sources. The grid was created using the 'Grid Index features', so it is a polygon. Some grid cells have no features, some have one, and some have several features from different layers.

I tried Batch Spatial Join and Batch Summarize Within. For some reason, both of these are only counting the last layer listed in the batch in their respective created columns "Join Count" and "Count of Points". How do I fix this issue? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I can comprehend that in the polygon layer you’ve multiple sources overlapping. So in order to get the count you’re using Batch spatial join on the Grid layer. But instead of using batch Summarize Within, can you directly apply it to your grid layer post spatial join?

Comment: Also see if this helps — https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221145/arcgis-10-3-1-spatial-join-count-of-points-on-a-regular-grid?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean by 'directly apply it to your grid layer post spatial join'. Could you clarify?

I did end up joining each toxic chemical source layer column 'count' to the grid layer, then summed all the counts in a separate column to get the totals in each grid. This I wanted to avoid with a quicker process.

To clarify on my end, I have:

1) 9 point layers and 1 polygon layer that are the toxic chemical sources

2) A grid that I made via Grid Index Features (my understanding is that this is therefore a vector)